# org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException:The target server failed to respond when reqest server in microservice

Tags: httpclient

when I using this command to to request server(Java 8 microservice):

```
    curl 'http://localhost:11001/soa/user/user/2176' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' -H 'DNT: 1' \
-H 'requestId: 2e0dddf9-17d9-42d9-8614-b44de17fe135' \
-H 'Accept: */*' -H 'clientId: 7c54ff40-f11e-41c0-8d31-4b26d6569b5a' \
-H 'Referer: http://localhost:11001/swagger-ui.html' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36' -H 'token: e565b7f4-9ea2-4685-b3e6-77bc686d4ecd' \
-H 'appCode: 101' -H 'appVersion: Unknown' --compressed
```

the server side log output is:

```
2019-08-26 16:26:11.978  INFO [soa-user-service,f0f180a04e719f67,dc56cc9033988ff7,false] 487 --- [io-11001-exec-6] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://192.168.2.80:11001: The target server failed to respond
2019-08-26 16:26:11.982  INFO [soa-user-service,f0f180a04e719f67,dc56cc9033988ff7,false] 487 --- [io-11001-exec-6] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {}->http://192.168.2.80:11001
2019-08-26 16:26:38.594  INFO [soa-user-service,133250a52b415c71,dd171ebf43d3534d,false] 487 --- [io-11001-exec-3] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://192.168.2.80:11001: The target server failed to respond
2019-08-26 16:26:38.595  INFO [soa-user-service,133250a52b415c71,dd171ebf43d3534d,false] 487 --- [io-11001-exec-3] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {}->http://192.168.2.80:11001
2019-08-26 16:26:40.403  INFO [soa-user-service,,,] 487 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2019-08-26 16:28:23.046  INFO [soa-user-service,f0f180a04e719f67,dc56cc9033988ff7,false] 487 --- [io-11001-exec-6] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://192.168.2.80:11001: The target server failed to respond
2019-08-26 16:28:23.047  INFO [soa-user-service,f0f180a04e719f67,dc56cc9033988ff7,false] 487 --- [io-11001-exec-6] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {}->http://192.168.2.80:11001
```

my httpclient version config is:

```
<commons-httpclient.version>3.1</commons-httpclient.version>
<httpclient.version>4.5.8</httpclient.version>
```

what should I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it is proxy software problem,close the proxy software it should be ok:

```
ss-local -c /etc/shadowsocks/shadowsocks.json
```